# Android emulator displays wrong layout for the google nexus 5 dimensions (1080x1920)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-emulator, nexus-5

I am having some problems with layouts in my android application. I have created multiple android resource directories, for multiple android devices. The problem stands when I try to test my app on a **nexus 5 emulator** the screen's layout is out of bounds, it is disproportionate completely. In my app all the layouts for the **layout-xxhdpi-1080-1920** seem completely alrigth, the problem arises when I start my app in an nexus 5 emulator. It seems that the emulator picks a different layout size and not the one is it supposed to.

And I also have one question reqarding layout creation. Is the any better way to cover as much android devices as possible, instead of making all layout resolutions: for example:  **-mdpi-460x800 , xhdpi-720x1290, xhdpi-1080x1920,** and so on ... It really takes about more than 18 layout directory types and it is quite a lot.

I already looked at all the documentation Supporting different screens.

Comment: Did you try the app on a real device? Sometimes, an AVD can show some things differently. A real device can give you a more correct idea.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, and  the layout that displayed on a nexus 5 device is not the right one. Still can't find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cover almost every android device in the world. To do this you need have device specific resources.

for android versions earlier than 3.2

```
layout-ldpi
layout-mdpi
layout-hdpi
layout-xhdpi
```

for android version 3.2 and higher

```
layout-sw360dp
layout-sw420dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
```

This is just an representative example, more information [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html) in android docs